# Automatically increment text field Access 2010 Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form that tracks documents. I need to assign document numbers automatically based on which section is creating AND what type of document it is, then auto increment that combination to add 1 every time the same combination is created.
for example:

> ### DocType            |  Section     |      DocIdentifier
>
> - Field Methods  |    QAQC   |        FMQA-01
> - Field Methods  |    QAQC   |        FMQA-02
> - Field Methods  |  Standards   |     FMWQS-01
> - Chemical Methods | Standards   |     CMWQS-01

I have tried a number of different things - this being my latest try. I have included a hidden field (showDocNum) in my form to concatenate the DocType & Section but am having a heck of a time figuring out how to add the numbers.

```
 Private Sub cboSection_Change()
 Dim strMax As String
     strMax = DMax("DocIdentifier", "tblDocuments")
     Me!Alpha = Me!cboDocType.Column(2) & Me.cboSection.Column(2) & "-" 
 Me!txtDocIdentifier = Me!Alpha &  Right(strMax, Len(strMax)) + 1
 End Sub
```

and

```
    Private Sub txtDocIdentifier_GotFocus()
    Dim varMax As Variant
        varMax = DMax("DocIdentifier", "tblDocuments")
        Me!txtDocIdentifier = Me!Alpha & Right(varMax, 2) + 1
    End Sub
```

I have also tried adding an extra field to my table fldNumber and attempted to combine fldAlpha with fldNumber to create a composite PK DocIdentifier. The groups assistance would be mighty appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to build a value that gets saved in your table? If so, what is the field name in the table and did you bind it to your form, and what is the control name on the form?  Does 'cboSection_Change' format it properly?

Comment: Yes it is saved at DocIdentifier and is bound. The alpha part works perfectly populating the Me!Alpha field and, in turn, the Me.txtDocIdentifier I just cannot get the numbering to work

Answer (score 0):

I just impressed myself, I made it work using

```
    Private Sub cboSection_Change()
       showDocNum = Me!cboDocType.Column(2) & Me.cboSection.Column(2) & "-"
    End Sub        

    Private Sub txtDocIdentifier_GotFocus()
       Me!txtSequence = Nz(DMax("[MyPKNumber]", "tblDocuments", "[ShowDocNum] ='" & Me.[showDocNum] & "'"), 0) + 1
       Me!txtDocIdentifier = "WQD" & [showDocNum] & Format([MyPKNumber], "00")
    End Sub
```

Thank you for your willingness to help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *AfterUpdate* event:

```
Private Sub cboSection_AfterUpdate()

    Dim Prefix As String
    Dim Identifier As Integer

    Prefix = Me!cboDocType.Column(2) & Me.cboSection.Column(2) & "-"     
    Identifier = DMax("DocIdentifier", "tblDocuments", "DocIdentifier Like '" & Prefix & "*'") + 1
    Me!txtDocIdentifier.Value = Prefix & Format(Identifier, "00")

End Sub
```

If you have a doc number, say, "FMQA-03", you can find the next this way:

```
NextDocNo = Split(DocNo, "-")(0) & Format(Val(Split(DocNo, "-")(1)) + 1, "\-00")
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to increment each individual Prefix separately from the others. This is incrementing them together